# Is there a python library that implements both sides of the AWS authentication protocol?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services

I am writing a REST service in python and django and wanted to use Amazon's AWS authentication protocol. I was wondering if anyone knew of a python library that implemented formation of the header for sending and the validation of the header for recieving?

Comment: Have you heard of pyaws?  I've used it and it worked great for what I needed it for, but I don't know enough about aws in general to say if it does what you want.

Comment: Nope this is the first I have heard of that. I will check it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this Library. I think it is the library you are searching for..

[CalNet](https://calnet.berkeley.edu/developers/downloads/CalNetAwsPython.html)

You can find some Python Code Samples [Here](https://calnet.berkeley.edu/news/entry/2005/11/10/01.html)

Answer (score 1):

[boto](http://code.google.com/p/boto/) is a Python library for AWS. I don't know however if it supports what you are asking for.

Comment: I know boto can form the aws header but I don't know if it can validate one.

Answer (score 0):

I think this [code](http://staff.science.uva.nl/~otsur/code/AWS_SignatureGenerator.py) does exactly what you want :)
I'll be happy to get comments for improvement if needed.